# Linear Programming with Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, linear-programming

I have installed Anaconda on my windows 10 and I am using it for Python. I have a class in Mathematical optimization and need a good package for basic LP. **Is there a "pre-installed" package that is good for LP in Anaconda, that I can just import to my python file, or do I have to install packages?** I the latter case, any suggestions on which packages that are good and available for Anaconda on Windows 10? I have heard that PulP is adequate, but also that it doesn't come "pre-installed" with the Anaconda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to install PuLP on top of Anaconda on Windows it looks like you need to run:

> pip install pulp

See pulp [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PuLP/main/installing_pulp_at_home.html)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I saw this as well during my google searches. Will this work on windows? It says: "osx-64" in the description.

Comment: Just updated to a different one that has win64 as the tag

Comment: Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-32 channels:
  - pulp 1.5.6*

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda pulp

Comment: This is the output when I typed "conda install -c primer pulp=1.6.1" in the cmd.

Comment: Do you have 64bit or 32 bit Andaconda installed?

Comment: 32bit is installed, would i be better of by installing the 64bit? I just installed it yesterday.

Comment: I would suggest using 64bit. It appears that there is not a prepackaged conda version of pulp for 32bit.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alex Fargus, but when i typed :C:\Users\Benjamin>conda install -c primer pulp=1.6.1  this was the output:
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .
PackageNotFoundError: Package not found: '' Package missing in current win-32 channels:
  - pulp 1.6.1*

You can search for packages on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda pulp

Comment: It worked! Your last comment worked perfectly. Thank you.